# ModalPopupExtender Overlay

Tags: asp.net, css, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

All,

REMEMBER: My overlay uses absolute positioning.

I am trying to fix an overlay issue with my auto-suggest menu when it resides inside the `ModalPopup` (that uses Ajax control toolkit's `ModalPopupExtender`). As the user types, the overlay appears under the popup, but I want it to appear over it.

So the simple thing was to change the `z-index` on my auto-suggest menu overlay, but still the overlay appears underneath the modal popup. So I opened the source code for `ModalPopupExtender` and looked at its `z-index`, and set mine to higher what it was using (they're using 10,000; I used 20,000). I thought that would fix it, but to no avail; my overlay is still underneath the popup. How can that be when my overlay `div`'s `z-index` is higher then their overlay's `z-index`?

I would appreciate any help on this.

After further investigation, I think this line is causing the modal popup to go in front of everything:

```
this._foregroundElement.parentNode.appendChild(this._backgroundElement);
```

The 'foreground element' is the popup `div` and the background element is a temporary `div` that I think spans the entire page.

OK, since I can't change this, any suggestion what I can do to fix my overlay that is attached to a `textbox` in the modal popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved.

Cause of the problem was the IFRAME that was used to display the overlay with low z-index value.